# Do I need to create trunk/branches/tags in a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, directory-structure

When creating a repository on our central server, do I need to create the folder structure of `trunk/branches/tags` or does Mercurial take care of all that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, don't do it.

You don't need them in Mercurial.

Edit: in Mercurial, tags and branches are first-class citizens. They get treated differently, whereas they're pretty much the same in Subversion.

You might want to read about [branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Branch) and [named branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches), and also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890723/mercurial-named-branches-vs-multiple-repositories) here on SO.

Comment: @Omar: you're welcome. I realized it was an half baked answer right after I posted it :/